# Streaming video in sections as 1 video

Tags: javascript, html, css, video-streaming

So let's say I have a video split into multiple sections and I upload those sections onto a site and get the link for them. Is it possible to play them back as 1 video in a video div?

Comment: Can you show the code you have so far? We are not here to give you code, but to help fix what you already have.

Comment: You can try to convert 1 sec video to Base64 and pass it as `src` attribute to video component. Every base64 of one sec should be append to src.